# How do I install Skype on computer so that anyone who logs in does NOT have to go through the initial config?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, active-directory, windows-7, domain-controller

I installed Skype when logged on to the (local) admin account. Now, when I log off that, and log on as myname on the domain, I have to click through the intial setup steps (after you've already run the installer) of Skype. So, I have to click next to get through the mic setup/test, and it asks me if I want to take a pic.

How do I get it so that any person who logs in can just open Skype and go straight to the login screen?

Windows 7 64 bit, 2008R2

Comment: +1 Would like to hear what people come up with. We reviewed using Skye for our video-chat solution, but went with Google Apps instead. See the [Skype IT Administrator's Guide](http://download.skype.com/share/business/guides/skype-it-administrators-guide.pdf) for getting started. Particularly, section 4.0, for configuration via Group Policy.

Comment: Probably for the same reason a user needs to set his/her own options in a program like Windows Live Messenger... some settings are user specific, written to either HKCU in the registry or to the users AppData folder.

Comment: @joeqwerty Exactly, hearing what those settings/files are would be *great* to translate into an ADMX or GPP CSE.

Answer (score 3):

It seems most of the configuration items can be set by group policy.  @jscott pointed you to the [Skype IT Administrator's guide](http://download.skype.com/share/business/guides/skype-it-administrators-guide.pdf), which is where you should be looking.

If you pre-populate the system settings and account .xml data as described in that guide I believe you'll be able to skip right to the login screen (you'll need to test this -- I don't have a Windows environment to play in).
If that doesn't work you probably have to set some values in the registry (under HKCU) so Skype thinks the configuration process has been completed -- It should be easy to compare a "working as desired" user's registry data to one that's bringing up the config screens.